# How to Install Ubuntu Server amd64 12.0.4.1 in Windows 2008 Hyper-V?

Tags: 12.04, virtualization, hyper-v

I would like to install Ubuntu Server 12.0.4.1 LTS in Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V.  However when I run the Ubuntu installation from the CDROM ISO, I get stopped by the error "Your installation CD-ROM couldn't be mounted...".

I found some references to this problem maybe being a bug.  I tried the following F6 parameters suggested by people experiencing this problem, but they did not work:
-- ata_piix.prefer_ms_hyperv=0
-- reserve=0x1f0, 0x8

I have been installing Ubuntu Server in Hyper-V since Ubuntu 8.0.4 LTS without any "CD-ROM" installation issues.  I'm not sure why version 12.0.4.1 no longer installs in Hyper-V.

Does anyone know how to install Ubuntu Server 12.0.4.1 LTS in Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V?

*Updated:  17:00 EST Dec 29, 2012*

I was able to install Ubuntu 12.0.4 using the mini.iso from the following archive.  However, I don't really consider this a solution because the procedure is technically not repeatable and I am not sure if I follow the same procedure a year from now I will get the same install or different versions.  Repeatability is important to me since I install additional software into the system after Ubuntu is installed.
[*http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/*](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/)

Comment: Me too Installed ubuntu in Hyper-v, May i know your Server Specification ?